# How can I resolve output data size error about neural network training in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a input file containing (17x127) data (Force) and a target file of (3x127)(True Stress).

I have written the following code for training the neural networks:

```
p=Force;
t=T_Stress;

net =newff(minmax(p),[10,1],{'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');

net.trainParam.lr = .05;        %Learning Rate
net.trainParam.epochs = 300;    %Max Ephocs
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-5;     %Training Goal in Mean Sqared Error
net.trainParam.show = 50;       %# of ephocs in display

[net,tr1] = train(net,p,t);
o1 = sim(net,p)
```

However I get the following errors:

> ??? Error using ==> trainlm at 109 Output data size does not match
>   net.outputs{2}.size.
>
> Error in ==> network.train at 107
>
> [net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the training parameters associated with the "trainlm" training function by looking for "trainlm" in Matlab help

Answer (score 0):

By calling newff with the parameter [10,1] you created a neural network with 10 neurons on the hidden layer and 1 on the output layer.
This does not match the number of outputs you are using. (3x127)
So either change the the newff call or use a different training dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As above commented "

> By calling newff with the parameter [10,1] you created a neural
>   network with 10 neurons on the hidden layer and 1 on the output layer

" you keep the value of output layer as 3 as you have three targets. The command will be as follows:

```
net =newff(minmax(p),[10,3],{'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
```